# VBA code to find cells containing "#N/A" in column B and copy the corresponding cell value in column A to a Text file

Tags: vba, excel

My requirement was to vlookup for data in 2 workbooks using vba. Now in the output of vlookup there are cells which did not match and hence their value is "#N/A"

Now how to select corresponding Column A values if "#N/A" is present in Column B and write them to a Text file.

Example excel file

```
Column A    Column B
A           1
B           #N/A
C           3
D           4
E           #N/A
```

The following output should be written in a Text file.

```
B
D
```

Please help me in arriving at this though VBA. TIA

Comment: What code have you tried by yourself? Have you tried the ISNA function? In VBA: `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(value)`

Comment: No.. How to use that ? I was trying to get this as string and search in the usedrange which dint work

Comment: You can loop trough your cells, and check for every cell value if the upper statement is true. When it's true, save the column you want. After you've had all records, you can print the text file.

Comment: I am New to VB, Wouter.. could you please provide me a sample code for it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub ToTextFile()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String, strFile_Path As String
    Dim strTxt As Variant

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(i, 2).Value)) Then
            If str = "" Then
                str = Cells(i, 1).Value
            Else
                str = str & "," & Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    strTxt = Split(str, ",")

    strFile_Path = "C:\temp\test.txt" 'Change to your file path
    Open strFile_Path For Output As #1

    For i = 0 To UBound(strTxt)
        Print #1, strTxt(i)
    Next i
    Close #1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column C with each cell having the array formula (hit ctrl+enter after pasting):

```
=IF(ISNA(B:B),A:A,"")
```

Then the body of your text file can be the following string

```
Debug.Print Join$(Application.Transpose( _
    Application.Index(Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange, 0, 3)), vbNewLine)
```